# Change VLC Home Directory

Tags: vlc

I just installed VLC 3.0 via snap. Unlike the previous versions nothing shows up now when I click "My Music" or "My Videos". I think it set the wrong base directory.
/home/gratis/snap/vlc/158 is where .cache , .config etc. are so I would guess that's currently set to be the home directory. I don't require VLC to move all it's files, I would just like it to locate my stuff, which is /home/gratis/Music ,and /home/gratis/Videos respectively.

Comment: Atm I believe those items in won't work, below answer about Media Library is best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Tools -> Preferences`, select `All` in `Show Settings`. Then select `Playlist` and enable `Use media library`.

[image: Enable Media Library in VLC]

Then select `Media Library` and right click on the white space to add a directory.

[image: Add custom directory]

Comment: Hi thanks for the use media library trick! I had tried all the rest before. Is there any way of saving Playlist View Mode -> Icons? As it stands I have to re-change that every time I launch a new instance of VLC

Comment: That's strange, in my case it remembers the `Icons` mode.

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to find an VLC option for this, however:

## Media Library

You can add directories to your media library.

Select the **library** in the VLC interface ,
then **right click in the empty space** *->* select **add folder** *->* select your **Videos/Music** folders.

## Symlinks

You could try to set symlinks* to the directory where VLC is looking for them, i.e.

```
ln -s /home/gratis/Videos /home/gratis/snap/vlc/158/Videos
```

(*)*I'm unable to test this at the moment*

Comment: hi, so I entered "ln -s /home/gratis/Videos /home/gratis/snap/vlc/158/Videos" and the same thing for music in the terminal, but unfortunately even after rebooting, still nothing shows up, when I click on "My music"

Thanks for your effort though, but I'll give the bounty to the other person, because I didn't know the use media library checkbox outlined below is what saves the directories I added the last instance